# Handle JWT token issued by google, from Spring-Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

can somebody show how to configure a SPRING-BOOT back-end (web app) to work with a JWT token, that is valid and issued for the back-end by google. I cannot find any example. The spring security configuration is missing something.

I've configured the Spring boot adapter to work with a web application. But it's a different flow. The redirects for Android for example do not pass through the back-end. And so a new user that is logging in from a mobile device has a valid token but doesn't trigger a login or registration process.

Kind Regards :)

Comment: You can use the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` from Spring Boot: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client/2.2.6.RELEASE  Tutorial from Spring: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: The mentioned client is already there. And the tutorial doesn't show how to authenticate a mobile device, that already obtained the JWT token from Google.